# Output of the Embedding layer in Decoder(Neural machine translation)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to understand Attention model using the following tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention

In the Decoder section it's written:

```
# x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(x)
```

I don't understand why embedding output is (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim). According the documentation(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) the output must be (batch_size, input_length, output_dim), which is in the case of tutorial (batch_size, max_len,embedding_dim).

Question: Why is secode dimension = 1, but not max_len?

Answer (score 1):

The model in this tutorial is a sequence to sequence.so at each step the model receives One word of the entire text. This is why the max_len in  (batch_size, max_len,embedding_dim) is equal to 1. each word is represented by ONE vector of size  = embedding_dim